# как вычесть datetime из datetime в python?

Tags: python, datetime

У меня есть две даты

```
dt_from = {datetime} 2017-04-30 00:00:00
dt_to = {datetime} 2018-03-30 00:00:00
```

Я хочу сделать

```
date = from - to
```

Но это выбрасывает исключение. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: добавьте код и само исключение в вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ваши `dt_from` и `dt_to` - строки, то преобразуйте их в `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt_from = '2017-04-30 00:00:00'
dt_to = '2018-03-30 00:00:00'

dt_from_datetime = datetime.strptime(dt_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
dt_to_datetime = datetime.strptime(dt_to, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

и потом уже вычитайте:

```
delta = dt_to_datetime - dt_from_datetime

>>> delta
datetime.timedelta(334)

>>> delta.days
334
```