# Вычесть datetime из datetime и получить datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Вроде не сложный вопрос, но перелопатил уже весь интернет, включая англоязычный.

Как в Python вычесть объект `datetime` из объекта `datetime` и получить не `datetime.timedelta`, а полноценный `datetime`?

Пример:

```
2023-04-02 07:55:50.342151 - 2023-04-02 07:55:50.342151 = 0000-00-00 00:00:00.0
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [как вычесть datetime из datetime в python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1225808/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-datetime-%d0%b8%d0%b7-datetime-%d0%b2-python)

Comment: А зачем это нужно с практической точки зрения?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Стандартных методов для этого нет по причине того, что `timedelta` - это не дата, а лишь промежуток времени, и представлять ее в виде даты достаточно странно.

Как бы вы, например, представили `timedelta = 5 minutes` в формате даты?

Это должно быть что-то в духе `0000-01-01 00:05:00`? Или может быть `1900-01-01 00:05:00`? Объективно логичного варианта представления здесь не найти, ваш вариант `0000-00-00 00:00:00.0` тоже не кажется логичным, поскольку нулевого года/месяца/дня не существует.

Основная проблема - непонятно, что является точкой отсчета, какой год, месяц, да и в целом - выглядит как-то странно, согласитесь.

Поэтому обычно желание произвести такое действие говорит о логической ошибке, объекты `timedelta` используют лишь для того, чтобы прибавить (или отнять) величину времени от заранее известной даты, которая будет начальной точкой.

Например:

```
import datetime

a = datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0)
b = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
print(type(a - b), a - b)
```

Вывод:

```
<class 'datetime.datetime'> 2023-03-08 23:55:00
```

Получаем объект типа `datetime`, который отличается от начальной даты на величину `timedelta`.

---

**В образовательных целях**

В модуле `datetime` минимальная дата (`datetime.datetime.min`) забита как `0001-01-01 00:00:00`.

Поэтому, в теории, можно конечно отталкиваться от нее и сделать примерно следующим образом:

```
import datetime

a = datetime.datetime.min
b = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
print(a + b)
```

Получим:

```
0001-01-01 00:05:00
```

Но все-таки заниматься подобным настоятельно не рекомендую :)

Answer (score 1):

### [Сложение и вычитание дат и времени](https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/8.2.php)

Нередко при работе с датами возникает необходимость добавить к какой-либо дате определенный промежуток времени или, наоборот, вычесть некоторый период. И специально для таких операций в модуле `datetime` определен класс `timedelta`. Фактически этот класс определяет некоторый период времени.

---

Для определения промежутка времени можно использовать конструктор `timedelta`:

```
timedelta([days] [, seconds] [, microseconds] [, milliseconds] [, minutes] [, hours] [, weeks])
```

В конструктор мы последовательно передаем дни, секунды, микросекунды, миллисекунды, минуты, часы и недели.

Определим несколько периодов:

```
from datetime import timedelta
 
three_hours = timedelta(hours=3)
print(three_hours)       # 3:00:00
three_hours_thirty_minutes = timedelta(hours=3, minutes=30)  # 3:30:00
 
two_days = timedelta(2)  # 2 days, 0:00:00
 
two_days_three_hours_thirty_minutes = timedelta(days=2, hours=3, minutes=30)  # 2 days, 3:30:00
```

Используя `timedelta`, мы можем складывать или вычитать даты. Например, получим дату, которая будет через два дня:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
 
now = datetime.now()
print(now)                      # 2017-05-03 17:46:44.558754
two_days = timedelta(2)
in_two_days = now + two_days
print(in_two_days)              # 2017-05-05 17:46:44.558754
```

Или узнаем, сколько было времени 10 часов 15 минут назад, то есть фактически нам надо вычесть из текущего времени 10 часов и 15 минут:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
 
now = datetime.now()
till_ten_hours_fifteen_minutes = now - timedelta(hours=10, minutes=15)
print(till_ten_hours_fifteen_minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Даже непонятно, что тут объяснять. У вас есть две даты: 9 марта 2023 года и 4 марта 2023. Вы вычли вторую дату из первой. Логичный ответ - 5 дней. А какой  "полноценный datetime" вы при этом хотите получить? Приведите пример. Даже интересно стало.